# How to remove the same value with comma and get the final value?

Tags: php

What I want to do is get the same value in array , remove the same value in array , then get the whole after removed the same value in array

**Here is my code, but stuck**

```
$userid = "1087,1088,1089,1090,1091";
$user_explode = explode(",",$userid);
$got_user = "no";
foreach($user_explode as $userid_row){
    if($userid_row == 1088){
      $got_user = "yes";
    }
}
```

**This is what I want**

```
$id = '1,2,3,4,5';
if($id == 2){
 $result = '1,3,4,5';
}
echo $result;
```

Any idea how to solve my problem ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not [`array_filter`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php)?

```
<?php

$id = '1,2,3,4,5';
$result = implode(',', 
    array_filter(
        explode(',', $id),
        function($id) {
            if ($id != 2)
                return true;
        }
    )
);

echo $result;
```

Result:

```
1,3,4,5
```

Answer (score 0):

You use [unset()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php) to remove the unwanted value.

```
$userid = "1087,1088,1089,1090,1091";
$user_explode = explode(",",$userid);
$got_user = "no";
foreach($user_explode as $key => $userid_row){
    if($userid_row == 1088){
      unset($user_explode[$key]);
      $got_user = "yes";
    }
}

echo(implode(',',$user_explode));
```

Answer (score 0):

you can explode to array, remove the item and back to array.

```
$userid = "1087,1088,1089,1090,1091";
$user_explode = explode(",",$userid);
$ids = array_flip($user_explode);
unset($ids['1088']);
$user_explode = array_flip($ids);
$final = implode(",", $user_explode);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [array_search](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) function to get the key for the value you are searching for.  If the key is found then unset the element from the array and finally implode the array and echo it out.

Try:

```
$userid = "1087,1088,1089,1090,1091";
$user_explode = explode(",",$userid);
$got_user = "no";

$found_key = array_search('1088', $user_explode);
if ($found_key !== false) {
  unset($user_explode[$found_key]);
}

$result = implode(',', $user_explode);
echo $result;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $id = "1,2,3,4,5";
    $got_id = false; // Not found by default
    $ids_array = array_map("intval", explode(",", $id)); // intval just to make sure these are correct IDs, I mean, transform them to integers
    $search = 2; // You're searching for id = 2

    foreach ($ids_array AS $key => $value)
    {
        if ($value == $search) // ID exists, remove it from the array and return the modified array
        {
            unset($ids_array[$key]);
            $result = implode(",", $ids_array);
            $got_id = true; // Found ID
            echo $result;
        }
    }
?>
```

Functions used:

[array_map](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php)

[explode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)

[implode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)

[intval](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php)

[unset](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one.

```
$userid = array("1087","1088","1089","1090","1091");
foreach($userid as $key=>$id){
    if($id == 1088){
        unset($userid[$key]);
    }
}
print_r($userid);
```